# Search functionality for every column with multiple conditions in Asp.Net Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search, c#-4.0, gridview

I am searching this from last one one but unable to achieve the expected output.
My project requirement is to give search functionality in the every asp.net Grid view.

I have referred some of the links but not got the expected output.

below is the link of search Grid view which is giving very good output by using jQuery.

But when I use paging then this functionality is working as expected.

For Example : lets say I have 1000 records in the table & i have shown all the thousand records with maximum 10 records per page by using asp.net inbuit paging 
functionality.

but when i search first name this only search & show me the results from the records which is currently displayed on the page (i.e. 10 records).

But expected output is to search from all the 1000 records.

Link I am referring is 
[Asp.Net gridview search link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-records-data-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx)

this link is not having multiple column searching like 
For example : 
If we search first  name with last name then both the column should be searched.

Please help me if you find any link related to above searching.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with JQuery QuickSearch plugin, because it is a client-side functionality, so it cannot guess what is in other pages.

You have many options here :

- [what I would do] you can make a postback where you can filter data efficiently with linq (and display only what the user wants to)
- [tricky] you can try to load everything and hide it (so you create a pager that hides or displays lines) and maybe you will be able to use Query QuickSearch
- you can add autocomplete on your textbox to show data which is matching (and display detail when chosen)